# Update wait times in table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a very simple website to show wait times for some restaurants. I need to create some back end script that allows restaurant managers to open a separate website and update the value for the wait time. Right now all I have is a simple table

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
  <th> Venue </th>
   <th> Style </th>
   <th> Availability </th>
 <th> Location </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>In Room Dining </td>
<td>Full Menus </td>
<td> No Wait </td> 
<td> </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

What would be the best way to create a user friendly interface to modify the "No Wait" portion of this? Should I create a  Javascript function with a text box that replaces the information in that cell? Any advice would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brief example of how to switch text on your table. My goal is to give you a starting point for what you can do and let you proceed with gathering additional resources and coding the rest of it as you see fit.

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Style</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>In Room Dining</td>
        <td>Full Menus</td>
        <td>
            <p id="availability">No Wait</p>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Swith Availability" onClick="switchAvail();">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function switchAvail() {
    var availability = document.getElementById('availability');
    availability.innerHTML = "1 Hour Wait";
}
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/0gph51bc/

As you can see there is a button on this example which when clicked, triggers `switchAvail()` to run. Inside of `switchAvail()` it says, 'Hey, go find the HTML Element that has the Id of `availability`'. Once found, switch the the stuff between it's tag's to reflect '1 hour wait'.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I am new to JScript building, but I catch on quick. If I build a var into this page lets say waittime.com. I can modify it from another page like waittime.com/IRD as long as they are both linked to the same script right? OH, and I have one more question. Would it be hard to password protect the waittime.com/IRD webpage so not just anyone could access it? Sorry I know this are newbie questions I just want to wrap my head around it before I go in deep.

Comment: `var` (or variables) when declared inside of a function only live until that function is complete. I believe if you are looking to solve how to have the status/information the restaurant manager posts, stay accurate to the end user who is curious about how long the wait is somewhere, that you will need to store that information in somesort of database. I am not too familiar with that side of things.